# Как правильно произвести замену img на svg?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Есть изображение `img svg`, которое вставлено на страницу с помощью тега `img`

```
<img src="name-image.svg" alt="">
```

Задача: изменить `fill` для данного изображения

Как вариант сделать замену `inline img` на `svg`

Может есть другие варианты решения данной задачи?

Comment: Тоже всегда мучал этот вопрос, это большая недоработка связки html/svg на мой взгляд. В зарубежном so предлагают аяксом подтягивать это картинки и заменять содержимым svg. Мне этот вариант не нравится, но и вариант сразу ставить инлайн svg тоже не привлекает

Comment: Поскольку менять свг можно только вставленный в html, то придеться его вставлять. Вставлять сразу инлайново или потом подтягивать яксом. Третьего не дано, увы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Задача: изменить fill для данного изображения

То есть нужно поменять цвет svg изображения. Это можно сделать с помощью `css` или `svg` фильтров

### CSS фильтры

Исходное svg изображение жёлтого колокольчика добавленное из сети в `HTML` с помощью тега `<img>`

```css
img 
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f514.svg">
```

С помощью различных css фильтров меняем цвет

```css
.twa-bell {
  background-image: url("https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f514.svg");
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  margin: 0 0.15em 0 0.3em;
  vertical-align: -0.3em;
  background-size: 3em 3em;
}
.grey-out {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.hue-rotate {
  filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
.invert {
  filter: invert(100%);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span class="twa-bell"></span>
  <span class="twa-bell grey-out"></span>
  <span class="twa-bell hue-rotate"></span>
  <span class="twa-bell invert"></span>
</body>
```

### SVG фильтры

SVG фильтры имеют более широкую поддержку по сравнению `CSS filter`
Фильтров SVG, которые могут быть использованы для изменения цвета, достаточно много.

Ниже пример использования `feColorMatrix`

Более подробно и доходчиво о настройках и использовании `feColorMatrix`
 [смотрите  в топике нашего сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/832558/28748)

Первый фильтр `id="dodgerFilter"` сразу перекрашивает иконку с жёлтого цвета на синий.

При наведении срабатывает второй фильтр `id="redFilter"`, который даёт красный цвет.

```css
.img1 
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
filter:url(#dodgerFilter);
transition: all 0.8s ease-in;
}
.img1:hover 
{
filter:url(#redFilter);
width:60px;
height:60px;
}
```

```html
<img class="img1" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f514.svg">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 130"> 
  <defs>
     <filter id="redFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 1
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
   <filter id="dodgerFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 1
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
    
   </defs> 
   <use xlink:href="#Building" x="0" filter="url(#RedFilter)" ></use>
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Очень интересная штука эти SVG фильтры. Спасибо! Периодически прохожусь по твоим постам, постоянно нахожу для себя что-то новое и интересное, что можно применить в жизни.

Answer (score 5):

### Хорошее, но большое решение задачи:

```js
jQuery('img.svg').each(function() {
  var $img = jQuery(this);
  var imgID = $img.attr('id');
  var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
  var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

  jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
    // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
    var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

    // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
    if (typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
      $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
    }
    // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
    if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
      $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg');
    }

    // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
    $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

    // Check if the viewport is set, if the viewport is not set the SVG wont't scale.
    if (!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
      $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
    }

    // Replace image with new SVG
    $img.replaceWith($svg);

  }, 'xml');

});
```

```css
svg path {fill: #000 !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Windows_logo_-_2012_%28red%29.svg" alt="">

<img class='svg' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Windows_logo_-_2012_%28red%29.svg" alt="">
```

Очень давно сталкивался с данной задачей, когда проще прикреплять `svg` в `img` во благо меньшего количества строк кода, но тогда ты не имеешь прямого доступа в изменению цвета через `svg path{fill: value}`, но метод выше более чем рабочий, если вы не брезгуете `jQuery`.

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11978996/7394871): @Drew Baker

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/11978995/7394871