# Перевeсти HEX или RGB в feColorMatrix значения и суть каждого из них

Tags: html, css, html5, svg, filter

Изображение svg в формате `base64`
Необходимо черной фигуре `svg`,  задать цвет `#26bf8c`. Но как его записать в значениях `feColorMatriх`?

```
<svg width='20px' height='10px' preserveAspectRatio='none meet'>
  <image filter='url(#colorMatrixFilter1)' width='20px' height='10px' xlink:href='../img.svg'/>
  <defs>
    <filter id='colorMatrixFilter1'>
      <feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0
                                           1 0 0 1 0
                                           1 0 0 0 0
                                           0 1 0 1 0'
      />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Что значит каждое значение(элемент) этой матрицы?

Comment: https://codepen.io/jacobberglund/pen/ORNQAr  это единственное что увидел и пока он есть там скачайте его

Comment: дополню ответом https://stackoverflow.com/a/50498763/873481 
https://beta.observablehq.com/@gitmullany/filter-effects-using-svg-color-matrices -- идеальный пример, все четко показывает по каждому значению матрицы!

Comment: @CodeGust да, `Michael Mullany` самый лучший специалист, на мой взгляд, по фильтрам на Enso. Всегда с интересом читаю его ответы.

Comment: [Добавлен новый ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1037432/28748), который позволяет легко с помощью CSS фильтров подобрать любой цвет

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ниже на рисунке показано, за какими строчками и столбцами закреплены определенные каналы цветов и прозрачности цвета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В крайнем, правом столбце, каждая строка,- это финальный результат выполненных матричных вычислений по определенным каналам.
 Первая строка отвечает за красный цвет (R). Если в этой строчке будет `"1"`, а в двух последующих строках нули, то результирующий цвет всей матрицы будет красный, чистый цвет, HEX`(#ff0000)`,`rgba(255,0,0,1)` или `rgba в % (100,0,0,1)`
Последняя строка,- это проценты прозрачности. `"1"` в этой строке соответствует `100%` прозрачности.

*Пример окраски в красный цвет:*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 130"> 
  <defs>
     <filter id="RedFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 1
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
      <image id="Building" width="150" height="150"  xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>   
   </defs> 
   <use xlink:href="#Building" x="0" filter="url(#RedFilter)" ></use>
 
</svg>
```

С одноканальным (R) красным цветом оказалось всё просто. Также просто будет получить зеленый цвет (G), для этого нужно поставить `1` во второй строчке последнего столбца матрицы.

**Для подстановки значений в матрицу  необходимо будет перевести шестнадцатеричные значения цветов (HEX) `#26bf8c` в `rgba в %`**

- С помощью инженерного калькулятора переводим: шестнадцатеричное
  число`26` это `38` в десятичной системе; `bf` - `191`; `8c` - `140`
  итого `rgba(38,191,140)`
- Переводим в проценты: `(38/255)*100 = 15%`
- Итого  будут значения `rgba в %` `(15,75,55,100)` или для
  матрицы `(0.15,0.75,0.55,1)`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 130"> 
  <defs>
    <filter id="RedFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0.15
                        0 0 0 0 0.75
                        0 0 0 0 0.55
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
       <image id="Building" width="150" height="150"  xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>   
   </defs> 
   <use xlink:href="#Building" x="0" filter="url(#RedFilter)" ></use>
   
   
</svg>
```

### 2# способ

перевода из `HEX` значений цвета в `rgba в %`

Этот способ намного проще, так как не надо ничего вычислять.

- Используется любая утилита, в которой есть возможность выбора и
  конвертирования цвета из одной формы записи в другую.  Для этих целей
  я использовал `ColorMania`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Копируем значение `HEX` цвета
2. Нажимаем установку цвета (Set)
3. Выбираем кодировку RGB % Value

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Забираем цифры в процентах и подставляем в виде - `1` соответствует 100% - `0.15,0.75,0.55,1` в последний, пятый столбец матрицы, как в первом способе выше.

Comment: спасиБо! очень толков разъяснили! 
только вот вопрос: если мы для красного поставили 0.15 значение, на что будут влиять 1й, 2й, 3й столбцы (4й-прозрачность), если их изменить?

Comment: @CodeGust просто пробуйте, это на словах очень. трудно объяснить матричные вычисления и как, каждый столбец и строка в нем влияют на конечный результат. Ведь объяснение 
 типа - доля красного в зелёном канале, не принесет же ясности в понимании процесса

Comment: спасибо за дополнение! со своей стороны, получил ответ и на англоязычном стаке, оттуда ссылка https://beta.observablehq.com/@gitmullany/filter-effects-using-svg-color-matrices на очень хорошо показывающий каждое значение в действии

Answer (score 6):

Это коэффициенты смешения цветов.

1. Каждая строка в матрице обозначает свой цветовой канал выходного изображения (красный, зелёный, синий и непрозрачность соответственно).
2. Коэффициенты в строке означают степень влияния каждого из входных каналов на конкретный выходной. Однако коэффициентов пять, а каналов всего четыре. Это связано с тем, что вы, возможно, захотите не просто смешать цвета, но и сдвинуть результат вверх или вниз, сделав канал безусловно темнее или светлее. То есть последний коэффициент сдвигает *чёрную точку* цветового канала.

В вашем случае:

```
    1 0 0 0 0        rвых = (1 * rвх) + (0 * gвх) + (0 * bвх) + (0 * aвх) + 0
    1 0 0 1 0   =>   gвых = (1 * rвх) + (0 * gвх) + (0 * bвх) + (1 * aвх) + 0
    1 0 0 0 0        bвых = (1 * rвх) + (0 * gвх) + (0 * bвх) + (0 * aвх) + 0
    0 1 0 1 0        aвых = (0 * rвх) + (1 * gвх) + (0 * bвх) + (1 * aвх) + 0
```

это означает следующее:

1. Красный канал остаётся как есть.
2. Зелёный формируется путём усреднения красного и синего каналов. Причём итоговая яркость будет в два раза выше исходной (так как оба исходных канала складываются на своей полной яркости) — результат может быть ярче максимально допустимого, что приведёт к отсечению значения.
3. Синий канал отбрасывается и замещается красным.
4. Альфа-канал (задающий *непрозрачность*) также складывается из двух каналов, зелёного и исходной альфы. То есть мы сохраняем исходную альфу, но теперь на степень непрозрачности влияют и зелёные оттенки.

Как это можно сочетать и использовать — остаётся на ваше художественное и дизайнерское усмотрение.

Answer (score 4):

### Способ замещения RGB цвета CSS фильтрами.

В ручную подбирать комбинацию фильтров CSS и их параметров довольно утомительное занятие.

```css
img {
filter: invert(61%) sepia(10%) saturate(2853%) hue-rotate(109deg) brightness(101%) contrast(85%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wK.png"/>
```

Но есть [замечательный генератор](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp), который можно скачать с Codepen или выполнить подборку фильтров онлайн.

Всё просто — копируем нужный цвет и получаем подборку CSS фильтров, реализующих нужный цвет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]